# Multithreading in Android - why doesn't my onCompleted callback get called?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, callback, facebook-android-sdk

So I'm trying to add multithreading to my app and I'm running into a weird issue. I create a new runnable to handle parsing all the data so that the application doesn't freeze while it's doing so, and then create a new thread to run that runnable. However, when the thread starts and run() gets called, I noticed it never calls onCompleted(). This is weird to me because if I take that exact block of code out of the run() part, it works perfectly.

Can anybody let me know what I'm doing wrong? I'm a bit new to multithreading in Java, so I would really appreciate it.

```
    Runnable parseRunnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            new Request(session, id + "/comments", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray msgs = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                        populateData(msgs);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Request next = response.getRequestForPagedResults(Response.PagingDirection.NEXT);
                    retrieveMsgs(next);
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    };

    Thread parseThread = new Thread(parseRunnable);
    parseThread.start();
```

I set a breakpoint at run() and at "new Request" which always gets hit, but when I set breakpoints for onCompleted(), those are never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread will finish when you reach the end of

```
public void run ()
```

I'm going to assume you don't get your callback because your thread has already finished since you call executeAsync (which will execute on a separate thread). Removing your thread altogether will probably fix your problem.

Comment: Ah wow, makes sense - I was running into some freezing issues in my app, and your comment showed me that I was looking in the wrong place for it. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, if this solved tour issue remember to up vote & accept the answer.